# Chaining methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, chaining

I want to chain methods in Javascript (using Node.js).

However, I encountered this error:

```
var User = {
    'deletes': function() {
        console.log('deletes');
        return this;
    },
    'file': function(filename) {
        console.log('files');
    }
};

User.deletes.file();


node.js:50
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
TypeError: Object function () {
        console.log('deletes');
        return User;
    } has no method 'file'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tests/isolation.js:11:14)
    at Module._compile (node.js:348:23)
    at Object..js (node.js:356:12)
    at Module.load (node.js:279:25)
    at Array.<anonymous> (node.js:370:24)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:42:22)
    at node.js:616:9
```

How could I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *not invoking* the `deletes` function (the string representation of the function is what is printed in the error trace).

Try:

```
User.deletes().file()
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is missing: `User.deletes().file(<filename>)`. I'm not sure, maybe this raise an error?