# Javascript Chain methods without wrapping them up

Tags: javascript

I need to chain up methods, checked :

1.
[JavaScript Chainable Method Delimma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599847/javascript-chainable-method-delimma)

2.
[Javascript chaining methods together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619930/javascript-chaining-methods-together)

3.
[Chaining methods in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131374/chaining-methods-in-javascript)

4.
[Javascript chaining methods and processing time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572718/javascript-chaining-methods-and-processing-time)

But these questions are not similar to mine. Here is my situation :

I have 2 methods: A(), B(). B() have to be executed after A() finished.

Here is my code:

index.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function A(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var results = data.results;

            $.map(results, function(v, i){
                var card = `
                <div class="card" id="${v.id}">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="${v.image}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">${v.name}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">${v.gender}</p>
                  <p class="card-epi">...</p>
                </div>
              </div>
                `;

                $(".movies").append(card);
            });


        },
        error: function(data){

        }
    });
}

function B(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var results = data.results;

            $.map(results, function(v, i){
                $("#"+v.id).find(".card-epi").text(v.name)
            });
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("errors in B()", data);
        }
    });
}

new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve(A);
}).then(function(result){
    B();
});
// A();
// B();
});
```

index.html

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>

          <head>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
          </head>

          <body>
              <div class="movies card-columns">

              </div>
          </body>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="movies.js"></script>

          </html>
```

I tried to use Promise, but it doesn't work for me.

Here is the JSFidlde :
https://jsfiddle.net/franva/8vuussrz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Just return the `$.ajax( ... )` from your function `A` and it will work like this:

```
function A() {
  return $.ajax( ... );
}

A()
  .then(function() {
    B();
  });
```

`$.ajax( ... )` already exposes promise-like API in jQuery. So you should directly be able to apply `.then()` on the result of `A()`.

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function A() {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        var results = data.results;

        $.map(results, function (v, i) {
          var card = `
                  <div class="card" id="${v.id}">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="${v.image}" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${v.name}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">${v.gender}</p>
                    <p class="card-epi">...</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  `;

          $(".movies").append(card);
          def.resolve();
        });
      },
      error: function (data) {

      }
    });
    return def.promise();
  }

  function B() {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        var results = data.results;

        $.map(results, function (v, i) {
          $("#" + v.id).find(".card-epi").text(v.name)
        });
        def.resolve();
      },
      error: function (data) {
        console.log("errors in B()", data);
      }
    });
    return def.promise();
  }

  A().then(function() {
    console.log('A executed');
    return B();
  }).then(function() {
    console.lob('B executed');
  });
});
```

Comment: good one , I didn't know there is Deferred() in jQuery. Will keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function A(){
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var results = data.results;

                ...
                ...
                ... 
            },
            error: function(data){
                ...
            }
        });
    }

function B(){
        $.ajax({
                ... 
                ... 
                ... 
            },
            error: function(data){
                ... 
            }
        });
    }

A().then(B); //Chained...
```

Comment: nope, `then` takes a function as input and runs it itself..
so in this case passing only `B` would execute it as well.. This is useful when you dont have to pass any additional parameters, it can also accept data  passed from resolver of `A` 
suppose `A` resolves to `true` then `B` would have `true` as first parameter value.

Comment: I believe my answer is better then other answers in this question. as I have better and shorter answer ;)

Comment: Hi M, thanks for your explanation. Your answer is same to 31piy. but he was the 1st to reply my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

just call B() in the success Handler of A()

Comment: sorry, I didn't state my question clear. In fact, in side the $.map(results, function (v, i) {
          var card = ....  I have another ajax call. Due to the async feature of javascript ajax call, I cannot put B() in side success Handler of A().